# Select top N after aggregating by key and another field in pyspark RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

assuming a data set like this:

```
(teamId, player, minutesPlayed)
(1, 'A', 33)
(1, 'A', 12)
(1, 'B', 5)
(2, 'C', 22)
(2, 'C', 15)
(2, 'C', 33)
(2, 'D', 0)
......
```

So every tuple represents how many minutes player played in a game per team.
So I would like to aggregate data per player per team and select top 10 most playing players per team. Assuming a much larger data set of course.
So let's assume team 1 has 15 players, we want to get top 10 by `minutesPlayed`

Resulting data set would be:

```
(1, 'A', 350)
(1, 'B', 330)
#... rest 8 players of team 1
(2, 'C', 500)
(2, 'D', 330)
(2, 'E', 250)
#... rest 7 players of team 2
#.... rest of team with 10 players with most minutes

def map_players(data):
    teamId = data[0],
    player = data[1],
    minutesPlayed = data[2]

    return ((teamId, player), minutesPlayed) # returning the combination of team and player (assuming this is the way to do it)

def reduce_players(p1, p2):
    # really not sure what to do here
    # p1 and p2 are just then minutes played (int)
```

result:

```
player_data_set.map(map_players).reduceByKey(reduce_players).collect() # take(10)?

(1, 'A', 350)
(1, 'B', 330)
#... rest 8 players of team 1
(2, 'C', 500)
(2, 'D', 330)
(2, 'E', 250)
#... rest 7 players of team 2
#.... rest of team with 10 players with most minutes
```

I would like to do everything within `reduceByKey` reducer and use only `.map` method for mapping.

Comment: Why are you doing this with an RDD and not a Dataframe? It would be much easier and also more performant.

Answer (score 0):

If you convert your data into a pyspark Dataframe you could do it like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window
(
    df
    .groupBy('teamId', 'player')
    .agg(F.sum('minutesPlayed').alias('minutesPlayedTotal'))
    .withColumn('rank', F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy('teamId').orderBy(F.desc('minutesPlayedTotal')))
    .where('rank <= 10')
    .show()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use RDD then you can do something like this:

1. reduce using `teamId` + `player` as key to calculate the total minutes played by each `player`
2. reduce using this time only `teamId` as key to get the list of players with their count of minutes played for each team
3. flatmap values to sort the list of `(player, count)` on descending  order and take first 10 values

Example:

```
from operator import add

rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([
    (1, 'A', 33), (1, 'A', 12), (1, 'B', 5), (2, 'C', 22),
    (2, 'C', 15), (2, 'C', 33), (2, 'D', 0)
])

rdd1 = rdd.map(lambda x: ((x[0], x[1]), x[2])) \
    .reduceByKey(add) \
    .map(lambda x: (x[0][0], [(x[0][1], x[1])])) \
    .reduceByKey(add)\
    .flatMapValues(lambda x: sorted(x, key=lambda a: a[1], reverse=True)[:10])

for p in rdd1.collect():
    print(p)
#(1, ('A', 45))
#(1, ('B', 5))
#(2, ('C', 70))
#(2, ('D', 0))
```